# What are the basic and important things I have to learn as a iPhone application developer?

Tags: iphone

What are the important things(concepts) I have to learn to develop iPhone applications.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356025/iphone-getting-started and possibly this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332039/getting-started-with-iphone-development

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

Answer (score 4):

Understand the [Design Patterns](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW6)  that Cocoa use. Pay particular attention to the Model View Controller pattern and make sure you know how to use it well (Fat models, thin Controllers). This will make your life a lot easier down the line!

Memory management rules has been covered already.

Learning your way around the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action). The more familiar you become with this site, the easier it will be to find the information you need. I have found a lot my time developing for iPhone is spent just navigating around the documentation looking things up.

Learn C, and understand how Objective C is different. A large part of this is understanding how [Objective C's messaging](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH104-SW1) is different to calling functions in C.

Learn [Key Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/KeyValueCoding.html).

Objective C is a dynamic language, which when you understand this means a lot of the wierdness of Objective C makes sense.